# From getting an array of strings to getting an array of key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, key-value

I'm using [npmscraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scraperjs). I have two nearly identical functions below, which i want to basically combine the results they return into one array in key-value pair format.

First function returns ['orange','apple','grape']

Second function returns ['www.orange.com','www.apple.com','www.grape.com']

---

(very simplified) sample data to scrape from foo.com ###

```
<p>orange <a href="www.orange.com">click here</a></p>
<p>apple <a href="www.apple.com">click here</a></p>
<p>grape <a href="www.graphe.com">click here</a></p>
```

---

```
// Begin node app
 var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');

 // first function
  scraperjs.StaticScraper.create('https://foo.com/')
    .scrape(function($) {
        return $(".entry p").map(function() {
              return = $(this).text(); 
       }).get();
    })
    .then(function(fruit) { 
        // after some cleaning up...
        console.log(fruit)
         //returns ['orange','apple','grape']
    })

-----------------------
 // second function gets the links
 scraperjs.StaticScraper.create('https://foo.com/')
    .scrape(function($) {
        return $(".entry a").map(function() {
              return = $(this).attr('href'); 
       }).get();
    })
    .then(function(links) {
        console.log(links)
         // returns ['www.orange.com','www.apple.com','www.grape.com']
    })
```

(EDITED) What I'd like is something like:

```
[{fruit: 'orange'; link 'www.orange.com'},{fruit: 'apple'; link 'www.apple.com'}]
```

Comment: `What I'd like is something like`  this is not a valid javascript construct ... did you mean the `[]` to be `{}` ... `return = ` ??? really? do you claim your code to actually produce the current output?

Answer (score 1):

so, you'll have two arrays

```js
var array1 = ['orange','apple','grape'];
var array2 = ['www.orange.com','www.apple.com','www.grape.com']

// combining them to create an object

var result = array1.reduce(function(obj, key, index) {
    obj[key] = array2[index];
    return obj;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```